# last element of owlcarousel slider missing animation when it moves left from center position

Tags: jquery, transition, owl-carousel-2

Check this link https://zenegy.com/medarbejder-app

I implemented a image slider here using owlcarousel.js plugin.

[image]

This is the actual order of the slider. but when third element moves to left from center, it doesn't fade.

before it comes to this attached view (pic B)

pic B
[image]

can anybody help so that it works like other elements?

Comment: `it lost its regular animation.` i am unable to see that

Comment: @AlivetoDie modified the question, hope its help